# How to create a function with parameters based on array

Tags: javascript, function, evaluation

I have an array with would simbolize parameters of a function.

For Example:

```
var params = ['name', 'age', 'email'];
```

and this information is created by another endpoint which return this array. and from this array I would like to create a function like this:

```
function (name, age, email) {
    //...
    //my custom code
    return result;
}
```

So as you can see I would like to automatically create functions and use each array element as an argument to that function.

Is there any way to achieve that without using `eval`?

It seems `new Function('name', 'age', 'email', 'fn body')` can't be generated on the fly as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make any sense. There's no point in "creating" functions with named parameters. What is the real problem here?

Comment: Do you really need to do this ? You can just expect an array or object as a parameter, and get what you need from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = Function.apply( {}, ["name", "age", "email", "return email;"] );

/*function anonymous(name,age,email) {
return email;
}*/

a(1,2,3);

//3
```

This has no concrete benefits over `eval` though and what you are trying to do could probably be done differently without needing to evaluate strings into code on the fly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply()`. Make sure the function body is the last member of the array.

```
Function.apply( null, your_array );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function with an array of parameters, use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). For example:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    alert(a + b + c);
}
foo.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);
```